# How to create a function that takes a matrix as an input?

Tags: matlab

I am new to MatLab.

Write a function that takes as input a matrix D ∈ R^(N×2), D_i = (x_i,y_i), and the period ω and returns a plot showing a fit of the data without noise.

I need help with creating the function that takes the input as a matrix and period ω. Here is what I have so far. Am I on the right track?

```
function F = fftfuntion(D, omega)
check = 0;
x = D(:,1);
y = D(;,2);
```

Comment: `D` and `omega` are the inputs to your function. But your function uses neither. `omega` is being overwritten even. And you use `P` which is not defined inside the function. Other than that, it is not clear what you are actually asking. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to ask something specific.

Answer (score 0):

You are on track but there are 3 problems:

First: you are using p variable inside your function which is not defined there. If it is defined in your main code you have to insert it to this function by adding an input to your function as p and when the function is called you have to put p there. Your other solution is to set p as a global variable which is not recommended.

`function F = fftfuntion(D, omega,p)`

Second: you have said that you need omega as an input and you are changing it with omega = 2*pi which is not right.

Finally I don't see any output which I think that's because you are not still done with the function.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have made the following changes above. Please see that the changes I made are correct. I am still trying to figure out how to code the output.